# get redis server time with redistemplate

Tags: java, time, redis

On Spring Boot

I want to get millis of Redis server with RedisTemplate.

Like this

redis> TIME

1. "1687736427"
2. "339025"
   redis> TIME
3. "1687736427"
4. "339285"
   redis>

But reference says, "Template does not Support Time".

Is there no way?

```
/* thank you!! lant. My code look like */
this.redisTemplate.execute(new SessionCallback<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long execute(RedisOperations operations) throws DataAccessException {            
        do {
            Long now = redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Long>() {
                @Override
                public Long doInRedis(RedisConnection connection) throws DataAccessException {
                    return connection.time();
                }
            });
        } while() 
    }
}
```

Comment: hahahhahaha  : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RedisTemplate provides an `execute` method that can execute Redis Command.

```
  Object execute = redisTemplate.execute(new RedisCallback<Long>() {
        @Override
        public Long doInRedis(RedisConnection redisConnection) throws DataAccessException {
            return redisConnection.time();
        }
    });
```

Actually, other redisTemplate methods  like `get()` also execute using `execute(RedisCallback<T> callback)`.

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().get("key");
```

`get` source code is

```
@Override
public V get(Object key) {

    return execute(new ValueDeserializingRedisCallback(key) {

        @Override
        protected byte[] inRedis(byte[] rawKey, RedisConnection connection) {
            return connection.get(rawKey);
        }
    });
}


@Nullable
<T> T execute(RedisCallback<T> callback) {
    return template.execute(callback, true);
}
```